# Can enemies see Twisted Fate's portal destination when teleporting into a bush?

Tags: league-of-legends

When playing Twisted Fate, if I choose to use his ultimate and teleport inside a bush, can nearby enemies see the destination animation (cards on the ground before Twisted Fate appears) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

The cards will appear on the ground, so are obscured (but not entirely *hidden*) by brush sprites. However, it is still *visible*, just not entirely apparent. Red/Green colorblind users will want to enable the colorblind mode in order to see this, however.

If TF's port isn't great, then the edge of the circle will be visible outside the brush and be clear as day.

It's decided *less* visible than Shaco's smoke when he Deceives out of a bush.

And, as was mentioned by Asgade, you can hear the distinctive card-shuffling sound regardless of whether or not you notice the cards.

Answer (score 2):

If they look hard enough or the placement of it is bad enough to stick out a bit, then yes they can.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, there's no light but the spell animation is mostly hidden by the actual cover of the brush.

You can also hear it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

This works like the "jump" from shaco, where you can see the smoke when he uses it. Tf cards (where he will land) it's visible from outside too.

Is the same for wards (since the patch changes), where you see the ward while someone is using it for teleport.

Edit: Ok I tested with my wife, and YES, you can see the ground with cards where Twisted Fate is gonna land. BUT you need to be in ranged sign of the brush (the brush must NOT be in the fog)

PS: Sorry i could not make SS, i am in a Mac running Boot Camp. I tried and I could not make any SS thanks to my video board, Sorry.